# get select dropdown value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code for drop down in wordpress template file. I want selected value of this drop down to edit that value.

```
<select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2">
    <option  value="">Select state</option>
    <?php 
        $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $state_id=$row->state_id;
            $state_name=$row->state_name;
            echo '<option value='.$state_id.'>'.$state_name.'</option>';
        }
    ?>     
</select>
```

I want selected value of this drop down on edit page. But in database state_id is saved not the state_name. How to get selected value in this drop down? So how do I do it???

Comment: so state name saved in another table..????

Comment: I have state table with state_id and state_name..

Answer (score -1):

You can do this for PHP,

```
 <?php 
    $SelectedStateId = 5;// state id which you wish to selected, i am taking 5 for ex.
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $state_id=$row->state_id;
        $state_name=$row->state_name;
        if($SelectedStateId  == $state_id){
          echo '<option selected value='.$state_id.'>'.$state_name.'</option>';
        }else{
          echo '<option value='.$state_id.'>'.$state_name.'</option>';
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: This is a PHP question, javascript/jquery is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: @StephanMuller I am totally agree with you. i had edited my answer.